# RTK Query autogenerated hooks do not exist

Tags: typescript, react-hooks, react-redux, rtk-query

I started a project recently and I use redux/toolkit and its queries API to manage my data.

I tried to use the [auto-generated hooks](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage-with-typescript#using-auto-generated-react-hooks) but I get an error from typescript saying they cant find them. Here's an example of code I wrote:

```js
export const elementsApi = api.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (build) => ({
    getElements: build.query<
      {
        rootParentId: string;
      } & GetElementReturnType,
      number
    >({
      query: (search) => ({ url: `Menu/GetFiles${search}` }),
      transformResponse: ({ data }: { data: BackendMenuType }) => {
        return {
          rootParentId: data.MenuId,
          ...getElements(data),
        };
      },
      providesTags: (result, _error, id) => [{ type: elements, id }],
    }),
  }),
});

export const { useGetElementsQuery } = elementsApi;
```

The error message I get when I try to get the hook :

```
Property 'useGetElementsQuery' does not exist on type 'Api<BaseQueryFn<string | FetchArgs, unknown, FetchBaseQueryError, {}, FetchBaseQueryMeta>, { getElements: QueryDefinition<number, BaseQueryFn<...>, string, { ...; } & GetElementReturnType, "api">; }, "api", string, unique symbol>'.
```

I made sure my VSCode was set to a version higher than 4.1+, as suggested by this issue.
[It is 5.0.4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwENm.png)

the typescript version installed in my devdependencies is also 5.0.4

Is there another thing I forgot to check?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably imported `createApi` from `@reduxjs/toolkit/query`, not `@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react` - so you used the non-hook version.